# Is it possible to test exception conditions using Ludibrio?

Tags: python, mocking

I've recently started using Ludibrio for mocking objects in unit testing.  So far it seems to be pretty streamlined, but I seem to have hit a snag when testing some failure scenarios and can't seem to find a solution online.

Some of the method calls I'm working with raise exceptions which I want to trap.  So I want my mock object to simulate these conditions by raising an exception on a particular call.  I tried doing it like this:

```
from ludibrio import *

with Mock() as myMock:

    def raiseException():
        raise Exception('blah')

    myMock.test() >> raiseException()

try:
    print myMock.test()
except Exception, e:
    print 'Error: %s' % e

myMock.validate()
```

The trouble is, raiseException() is evaluated when the mock object is built, rather than when myMock.test() is called.  So clearly this isn't the correct way to do this.

Is there a way to get the mock object to raise an exception at runtime?  Or would the exception be intercepted as a failure and not get outside of the mock object anyway?

Answer (score 2):

Further Googling has eventually yielded the answer.  Simply tell the mock object to pass back an exception.  This appears to then be raised on the outside:

```
myMock.test() >> Exception('blah')
```